# How to prevent duplicate blog post dates in shopify

Tags: date, shopify, article

I have a blog with posts on a shopify website. I want to get all the publication dates of posts, and I do it like this:

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
   {{ article.created_at }}                 
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the output result:

```
2022-02-01 14:50:06
2022-01-25 05:25:33
2022-01-25 05:24:48
```

The result shows that there are two posts with the date **2022-01-25** and one post with the date **2022-02-01**. But all these dates have different **seconds** and **minutes**.

I want to remove seconds and minutes by setting the format to `date: "%B %Y"`:

```
{{ article.created_at | date: "%B %Y" }}
```

And in the end I get this result:

```
February 2022
January 2022
January 2022
```

Now the question is: How do I prevent duplicate dates with the same format `date: "%B %Y"`?

I can easily solve this problem with **javascript**, but I want to know if it's possible to solve this problem using only **shopify** features.

I will be glad to any answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the dates in as string

```
{%- capture dates -%}
{%- for article in blog.articles -%}
   {{ article.created_at | date: "%B %Y" }},            
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

And `split` and `uniq` the values to get only the unique ones:

```
{% assign unique_dates = dates | split: ',' | uniq %}
```

This will remove any values that are repeating.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but your code doesn't output anything.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov You need to loop the newly created variable `unique_dates` the same way `{% for date in unique_dates %}{{date}}{% endfor %}` or just output it as a string `{{ unique_dates | join: ','  }}`

Comment: That helped. I just forgot to add `{{ unique_dates }}`. Thanks!